# O que fazer quando recebo downvotes sem motivos?

Tags: debate

Desculpes, é a primeira vez que tenho perguntando aqui, até por não saber direito como funciona o meta, mas creio que seja para discussão sobre o Stack Overflow. Recente postei uma pergunta e ela estava em +7, quando entrei novamente ela estava em +6, ou seja, recebi um downvote sem mesmo nenhuma explicação. Tudo bem, a pessoa tem o total direito de não agradar da pergunta! Pergunta que mencionei: [Como é gerado o GUID (Identificador Único Global)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/184538/como-%C3%A9-gerado-o-guid-identificador-%C3%9Anico-global)

Ok, fiz outra pergunta esses dias [Como obter nomes de coluna de uma tabela no SQL Server?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/187368/como-obter-nomes-de-coluna-de-uma-tabela-no-sql-server/187376#187376) e eu mesmo respondi a minha pergunta.

Ela estava em +2 na pergunta e +5 na resposta e quando entrei de novo estava em +1 e +4! Minha opinião (ou pode ser que eu esteja errado também) é que tem alguém me dando downvote por não gostar de mim. O que devo fazer?

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/652/voto-negativo-sem-justificativa-%C3%A9-v%C3%A1lido

Comment: @MagicHat rs de boa!

Comment: @diegofm seu comentario deixou bem claro aqui também, vlw demais. Pode ser duplicata?

Comment: Eu posso falar dessa segunda porque teve uma sinalização dizendo que você não poderia perguntar e responder. O usuário foi orientado que isto é normal e de certa forma até desejável. Não posso afirmar a relação dos negativos, mas tem uma boa possibilidade. Infelizmente é um caso isolado que não pode ser comprovado, então também não tem o que fazer.

Comment: @bigown Tá ai o porque. Ele tem todo direito! :/

Comment: O negativo não é meu, nem vi motivo evidente para tal, mas duas coisas são importantes aqui: 1) Primeiro, parta sempre do pressuposto que a pessoa tem algum motivo justificável. Pensando assim, você sempre relê seus posts e pode achar algo pra ser melhorado ou esclarecido, e já não cria um hábito de receber negativamente críticas alheias (o -1 não deixa de ser uma crítica). Use como oportunidade de revisão. 2) Analisado o 1 e visto que realmente é um equívico, má intenção, ou "estratégia", nada a se preocupar, pois mal faz cócegas na reputação, ainda mais quando é no meio de muitos positivos.

Comment: Agora, se notar que é uma perseguição, aí sim é o caso de acionar a moderação, mas sem ficar paranóico, claro. Se acontecer, e esperamos que não aconteça, você provavelmente vai perceber pela quantidade, frequência, horários etc.

Comment: @Bacco sim já tomei muito -1 aqui no começo, e pelo meu ponto de vista foi mais que merecido pela má formulação das  perguntas e preguiça em entender do assunto. Agora essas duas perguntas foram recentes e no meu ponto de vista não cabia um -1. :)

Comment: minha opinião é que downvotes deveriam exigir uma justificativa e ainda ser possível ver o nome de quem votou, igual os likes do facebook.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basicamente, nada.

> *[...] tem alguém me dando downvote por não gostar de mim*

Essa afirmação pode ou não ser verdadeira, mas é impossível presumir má fé de um usuário só porque o saldo de votos das suas publicações são positivas. Existem uma série de motivos para um voto ocorrer e é óbvio que não temos como saber com certeza qual a intenção do votador.

Obviamente ao ver um problema com a publicação o certo é comentar junto (ou não) do *downvote*, mas parece que nem todo mundo está disposto a ajudar dessa forma.

Acredite, isso acontece com muitos usuários e com muita frequência (inclusive estes dias [uma resposta minha com 22 votos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102682/18246) e [uma pergunta com 68 votos positivos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/18246) receberam *downvotes* sem explicação), infelizmente não há nada que possamos fazer.

Casos extremos, como votos em sequência, entre outros sempre são tratados automaticamente pelo sistema e/ou pela equipe de moderadores. Também é possível avisar a equipe se você perceber que tem algo errado, que eles vão avaliar e te dar uma posição sobre a situação.

Comment: Esclareceu minha dúvida, então nada a fazer rs. Paia:/ 
Cheguei até sinalizar uma vez, mas minha sinalização parece que pegou foi mal rs.

Comment: É, @Marconi. Infelizmente o site tem menos usuários dedicados a fazer do SOpt um lugar melhor do que usuários dedicados a sair por aí clicando nas setas de *downvote*.

Comment: Nem todo downvote sem explicação é por implicância ou de sacanagem. Algumas pessoas não justificam para evitar represálias ou discussões, comigo mesmo isso já ocorreu diversas vezes em que tentei deixar um comentário. É uma opção da pessoa, nem todos levam na boa o -1 neste site e eu prefiro não ficar arriscando quem vai entender e quem não vai.  No caso dos posts linkados, realmente ficou meio estranho, ambos posts me pareceram muito bons e nao vi nada que justifique negativos.

Comment: Os maníacos dos Downvotes ainda é um problema sem solução proposta.

Comment: Acabou de acontecer isso [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/533419/bootstrap-card-com-com-100-da-altura-e-scroll), galera tóxica demais, procurei a resposta por meses no SO, SOPT, Google, DuckDuckGo entre outros, não achei em lugar nenhum, forneci o código completo no post, seguindo as recomendações de modelo mínimo verificável, fui claro na pergunta, não respondem, não comentam, e dão downvote, ridículo.